# вывод данных из localStorage с помощью JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

```js
function addMsg() {
 let doc = document,
  msgName, 
  msgDesc, 
  msgDate, 
  html;
 if (doc.getElementById('name').value) {
  msgName = doc.getElementById('name').value;
 } else {
  doc.getElementById('name').focus();
  return;
 }
 if (doc.getElementById('desc').value) {
  msgDesc = doc.getElementById('desc').value
 } else {
  doc.getElementById('desc').focus();
  return;
 }
 msgDate = doc.getElementById('date').value = new Date();
 html = '<section class="msg"><div><span>By ' + msgName + '</span><span>' + msgDate + '</span></div> <p>' + msgDesc + '</p></section>';
 
 let test = {
  name: msgName, 
  desc: msgDesc,
  date: msgDate 
 }
 
 localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(test)); 
 
 //if (doc.getElementById('result').innerHTML += html) doc.forms.myform.reset();
 
 let testMSG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
 
 if (doc.getElementById('testMSG').innerHTML += html) doc.forms.myform.reset();
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 3px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="right" id="testMSG">
</aside>

<!-- form msg comm -->
<section class="form-box">
  <form id="myform" action="">
    <input id="name" value="" placeholder="Type your nickname here..." name="login" >
    <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Write your comment here..." name="msg"></textarea>
    <input id="date" type="hidden" />
    <input value="OK" type="button" onclick="addMsg()" />    
  </form>
</section>
```

Добрый день!
Пытался освоить для себя возможности localStorage, запись идет на отлично.
Но после перезагрузки страницы, данные на сохраняются. 
Подскажите в чем дело.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В Хроме и ФФ, вроде бы, все работает.  Где тестите? Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: запись в localStorage проходит без ошибок. Как мне вывести информацию из localStorage?

Comment: Скрин http://prntscr.com/i0lzhg

Comment: В Вашем вопросе идет речь о том, что Вы не можете организовать вывод данных из LocalStorage. Однако, по факту,  данные выводятся, а проблема  в том, что у Вас не получается добавить данные в разметку, сохранив при этом предыдущие. Измените вопрос.

Comment: прошу прощение, неправильно мысли организовал! 
Результат не сохраняется после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Не сохраняется в разметке или LocalStorage?

Comment: результат не сохраняет в разметке

Comment: Ну, изначально, их же нет в разметке. Они же должны как-то попасть туда. Кто их будет выводить? Для этого нужно: во-впервых, данные в LocalStorage не заменять, а добавлять; во-вторых,  при загрузки страницы, необходимо обратится в LocalStorage, получить данные и вывести их на страницу; в третьих, на всякий случай, с Localctorage можно работать как с обычным объектом, в котором данные хранятся в виде строки, например, `var test = JSON.parse(Localstorage.test)`. Т.к. Вы пробуете освоить LocalStorage - писать код не буду. Попробуйте, для начала, сами

Comment: localStorage это просто хранилище, сам он не будет извлекать данные, эта часть лежит на вас. Самое просто что можно сделать это при загрузке страницы обратиться в localStorage и получить из него данные и вывести в форму.

Comment: Не получается у меня добавление значений, они заменяются. 
С выводом тоже проблема из LocalStorage, не могу найти пример, который бы подробнее объяснил